# Recycler view show wrong items in fragment with multiple view holders

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have activity that contain view pager with dynamically created fragment and inside the fragment a recycler view with multiple view holders that showing the data. The data at the first time are displayed correctly but when i scroll up down the data displayed in wrong positions . my the items are text and images downloaded and displayed using `Glide` so i will show some of the adapter main code because it's very long

The `onCreateViewHolder` method

```
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // the current view holder
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_HEADER:
                View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_article_header, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(headerView);
                break;
            case TYPE_EXTRA_INFORMATION:
                View extraInformationViewView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_article_extra_information, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ExtraArticleInformationViewHolder(extraInformationViewView);
                break;
            case TYPE_TEXT:
                View textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_content_text, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TextViewHolder(textView);
                break;
            case TYPE_IMAGE:
                View imageView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_content_image, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ImageViewHolder(imageView);
                break;
            case TYPE_TITLE:
                View titleView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_content_title, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TitleViewHolder(titleView);
                break;
            default:
                View emptyView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.item_article_empty_view, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new EmptyViewHolder(emptyView);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

The `onBindViewHolder` method and the init methods they for binding the data

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String type = "";
        if (position - 1 > 0 && position < article.getContent().size()) {
            type = article.getContent().get(position - 1).getType();
        }
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            initHeaderBindViewHolder((HeaderViewHolder) holder);
            break;
        case TYPE_EXTRA_INFORMATION:
            initExtraInformationBindViewHolder((ExtraArticleInformationViewHolder) holder);
            break;
        case TYPE_TEXT:
            initTextViewHolder((TextViewHolder) holder, position);
            break;
        case TYPE_IMAGE:
            initImageViewHolder((ImageViewHolder) holder, position);
            break;
        case TYPE_TITLE:
            initTitleViewHolder((TitleViewHolder) holder, position);
            break;
        case TYPE_VIDEO:
            initVideoViewHolder((VideoViewHolder) holder, position);
            break;
        default:
            initEmptyViewHolder((EmptyViewHolder) holder, position);
    }
    }
```

The `getItemViewType` method and the methods in the if a utils methods to determine the correct view holder

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isArticleItemHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        } else if (isArticleItemExtraInformation(position, article)) {
            return TYPE_EXTRA_INFORMATION;
        } else if (isArticleItemText(position, article)) {
            return TYPE_TEXT;
        } else if (isArticleItemImage(position, article)) {
            return TYPE_IMAGE;
        } else if (isArticleItemTitle(position, article)) {
            return TYPE_TITLE;
        } else {
            return TYPE_EMPTY;
        }
    }
```

The image view holder  init method

```
  private void initImageViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder) {
        //Check separator
        List<Content> contents = article.getContent();
        boolean isUpSeparator = false;
        boolean isDownSeparator = false;
        if (holder.getAdapterPosition() != 1 && holder.getAdapterPosition() != contents.size()) {
            //Check up separator
            if (holder.getAdapterPosition() - 2 > 0) {
                if (contents.get(holder.getAdapterPosition() - 2).getType().equals(CONTENT_SEPARATOR)) {
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.contentContainer.getLayoutParams();
                    params.topMargin = (int) dpToPx(context, 4);
                    isUpSeparator = true;
                }
                //Check down separator
            } else if (holder.getAdapterPosition() < contents.size()) {
                if (contents.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getType().equals(CONTENT_SEPARATOR)) {
                    isDownSeparator = true;
                }
            }
        }

        Content content = article.getContent().get(holder.getAdapterPosition() - 1);
        if (content != null) {
            if (content.getType().equals(CONTENT_IMAGE)) {
                if (content.getImage() != null) {
                    if (!content.getImage().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        boolean isImageSmallThanScreen = false;

                        //determine if an image is gid or not to change the placeholder
                        if (content.getImage().trim().contains(".gif")) {
                            holder.placeHolderImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.gif_place_holder);
                        }

                        //set the total margin in the article width in the current case we take
                        //6 form right and 6 from left
                        float marginDistance = dpToPx(context, 12);

                        //get the article width
                        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                        float dpWidth = (displayMetrics.widthPixels - marginDistance) / displayMetrics.density;
                        float viewWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels - marginDistance;

                        //check if the image size is bigger than the screen dp
                        if (dpWidth > content.getWidth()) {
                            isImageSmallThanScreen = true;
                            viewWidth = dpToPx(context, content.getWidth());
                        }

                        //get the ratio
                        float ratio = (float) content.getWidth() / (float) content.getHeight();

                        //set the new view height
                        float viewHeight = viewWidth / ratio;

                        //set the image size for the place holder
                        holder.contentImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) viewHeight;
                        holder.contentImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) viewWidth;

                        //the radius to set to the corner of the view
                        float cornerRadius = dpToPx(context, 12);

                        //check the text is first or the last to put separator
                        if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == 1 || isUpSeparator) {
                            holder.contentContainer.setTopRightCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
                            holder.contentContainer.setTopLeftCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
                            holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_separator_gray);
                        } else if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == article.getContent().size() || isDownSeparator) {
                            holder.contentContainer.setBottomLeftCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
                            holder.contentContainer.setBottomRightCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
                            holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_separator_gray);
                        } else {
                            holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundColor(context.
                                    getResources().getColor(R.color.text_typo_background));
                        }

                        //load the article content image
                        boolean finalIsImageSmallThanScreen = isImageSmallThanScreen;
                        boolean finalIsUpSeparator = isUpSeparator;
                        boolean finalIsDownSeparator = isDownSeparator;
                        GlideApp.with(context)
                                .load(content.getImage().trim())
                                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e,
                                                                Object model, Target<Drawable> target,
                                                                boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model,
                                                                   Target<Drawable> target,
                                                                   DataSource dataSource,
                                                                   boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        holder.placeHolderImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                        //if the image is small than the device width set the background to white
                                        if (finalIsImageSmallThanScreen) {
                                            if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == 1 || finalIsUpSeparator) {
                                                holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_separator);
                                            } else if (holder.getAdapterPosition() == article.getContent().size() || finalIsDownSeparator) {
                                                holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.down_separator);
                                            } else {
                                                holder.contentContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                })
                                .into(holder.contentImage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be good...

Comment: You need to post the init code. That's where the views are populated with data.  Also why aren't you using the position values?

Comment: ok i will post one of them i don't understand the second part

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a sample app that does this and tested. So if you are still having issues, please feel free to download this. I will leave it up for a month at least.

[Sample Dynamic ViewHolders](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwlwp8LqUnIZbXZuVVRTSW1CelU/view?usp=sharing)

I'm not sure how you're current code can work. Recycling does not decide which view to send back around to get reused based on your needs, you are simply getting the next recycled viewholder no matter what unless you specify which viewholder you need by overriding the getItemViewType and return the correct one.

I am assuming that you are trying to populate a "dynamic" list of content where the view is varying based on the model that is displaying. A very common scenario actually.

However, you are checking the type of viewModel on the recycle (aka bindView) and determining which init to do. This does not appear correct.

Imagine I have a list like this:

1. header (headerViewModel init) to view 1
2. text item (itemViewModel init) to view 2
3. Image item (imageViewModel init) to view 3

Then you have a list of dynamic items like this:

1. header
2. text
3. image
4. image
5. text

Now the first pass through it will look great as you are creating them for the first time so 1 through 3 are perfect.

Now let's imagine you only recycle 3 views and its a tiny screen :) for simplicity.

View 1 dissappears as you scroll down the list and gets reused for item 4
The new look is like this:

1. (item 2) View 2 = TextViewModel (shows correctly)
2. (item 3) View 3 = ImageViewModel (shows correctly)
3. (item 4) View 1 (recycled) HeaderViewModel (binding to Image)

So as you can see you are using the wrong model on recycle for the dynamic list.

To fix this your model should drive the holder used, not the type that was used on last recycling.

I think you will get the picture. Let me know if that makes sense.

The key is to let the model drive the type of viewholder not the recycler since you are being dynamic for your layout. goodluck.

Comment: i now maybe understand the problem .but i that is not work for me or need some modification i have one module with feild in it called `type` that feild what indicate what module i will update the current bindview holder method after follow your answer know the views is show wrong data from the first time and after scroll also . but thanks very much at fisrt i don't understand it so help me with the current code

Comment: You are closer. However, you are still not handling the case in which you get the wrong ViewHolder type for the current Position's Data Type. As that scenario will happen 80% of the time, so you need to handle this

Comment: how shoul i handle it

Comment: i saw this tutorial and i think i will refactor my code to this https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e

Comment: Ok so I didn't want to try and write all the sample code so I was trying to find a good example. I believe I have found one for you. Let me know if this makes sense to you. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: So the above example is basically letting the item drive the viewHolder instead of letting the viewHolder attempt to fit the item as that will never work dynamically, so you have to be dynamic in which view and viewholder is used as well if your list type is dynamic

Comment: so i should use `viewHolder.getItemViewType()` instead of check the holder instance ?

Comment: Yes, and the key is your method for getItemViewType you want to debug and make sure it is returning the correct "expected" int for the current position data model that you are processing in the bindView if you set it up correctly it should recycle the next appropriate type that you need I believe.

Comment: Ok so what is the current behavior. Like do you see text trying to fill a imageView holder or image trying to fill a textViewHolder, or is it just out of order but the content is correct? Where are we currently at in terms of troubleshooting. Does the getViewtype return the correct item int for the data at that position, have you confirmed that through debugging?

Comment: I'm also happy to take a look if you can deliver to me functional code that i can just open and debug.

Comment: do you have team viewer that you can access my computer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154727/discussion-between-sam-and-ahmed-abd-elmeged).

Comment: In a nutshell,  "your model should drive the holder used, not the type that was used on last recycling" - great answer, even without the sample code!

Answer (score 0):

The *onBindViewHolder* returns both viewHolder and position. You must use this position to bind the data to the view.

```
if (holder instanceof ImageViewHolder) {
        initImageViewHolder((HeaderViewHolder) holder, position);
    }
```

And then

```
private void initImageViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
List<Content> contents = article.getContent();
Content content = contents.get(position);
// other statements
}
```

The adapter position of viewholder is not updated until the view is rendered. So you must use the position supplied by the `onBindViewHolder`.

Here is the doc for on `onBindViewHolder`

> ```
>      * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should
>      * update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at the given
>      * position.
>      * <p>
>      * Note that unlike {@link android.widget.ListView}, RecyclerView will not call this method
>      * again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is
>      * invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only
>      * use the <code>position</code> parameter while acquiring the related data item inside
>      * this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later
>      * on (e.g. in a click listener), use {@link ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()} which will
>      * have the updated adapter position.
>      *
>      * Override {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)} instead if Adapter can
>      * handle efficient partial bind.
>      *
>      * @param holder The ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the
>      *        item at the given position in the data set.
>      * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
> ```

```
    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position);
```

Comment: i use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` at the method what is difrrence

Comment: the problem still there not fixed